# Reassign user with nil id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I ran into a surprising Rails/Rspec/FactoryGirl (?) quirk today. I've since found a solution, but I'm interested in why the problem happened in the first place.

My example:

```
let(:old_user) { build(:user) }
let(:new_user) { create(:user) }
let(:post) { build(:post, user: old_user) }

it 'sets the new user' do
  post.user_id = new_user.id
  post.save
  post.reload
  post.user.should == new_user
end
```

This test fails. The user is not assigned properly, at the end of the test `post.user` is still `old_user`. (It also is a completely useless test.)

There are a couple of ways to get the test to pass. One is to `create` the `old_user`, so that `post.user_id` is set before trying to reassign it. Another is to replace `post.user_id = new_user.id` with `post.user = User.find(new_user.id)`. But I'm curious...

What's happening behind the scenes with the original code when the test fails?

Edit: Adding in the factories as requested.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # We actually use Faker, but for this purpose I gave strings
    name 'Test User'
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'changeme'
    password_confirmation 'changeme'
  end
end

# The Post class has `belongs_to :user`
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    body 'I am a post'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you include your factories for `build(:user)` and `build(:post)`?

Comment: Wow, very cool!  I was able to reproduce the problem.  Another way to work-around the problem is to simply insert "post.user" between the assignment of the user_id and the save.   It seems that there is a "pending association" between the post and the old_user.  Explicity assigning a value to the foreign key doesn't disrupt that pending association so when you do post.save the old_user record is saved and the id is assigned to the fk.  By doing "post.user" before the post.save we then reload the associated user which cancels the pending association.

Comment: @tyler - done, they're pretty standard.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn - oh, interesting, I didn't find that fix. Yeah, it must be something with the "pending association" but I don't understand how it works. Some black magic...

Comment: Well, my conceptual model is... you have these object-to-object associations in memory which get translated into an fk-write at the time you persist the objects to the database. But until you do that save, the rails associations remain object-to-object.  Just because you tried to sneak in a new value for fk doesn't mean the association disappears.  When I pry'd into the post I could see the fk had changed to "1" as expected, and then immediately became "2" after save, so it obviously didn't care that you'd put something in the fk.  Anyway, good question!